# Communication between popup.js and background.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have started to implement a Chrome extension that is designed to present the user with the links from an RSS feed.

The browser action extension contains a background script (bg.js) and a popup.html with jQuery and a popup.js

As far as I can tell, everything is running fine up to the point where `callback()` should be called in bg.js and received in popup.js. It seems that the callback in popup.js is never triggered.

I checked both background page console and popup console ... no errors.

What do I need to change in order to receive the repsonse from bg.js?

Btw: What's the difference between using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.extension.sendMessage`?

The manifest.json looks like

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "heise Newsticker",
  "description": "Der RSS-Feed des heise Newstickers.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "icons": {
      "128" : "logo128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.heise.de/newsticker*",
    "http://heise.de.feedsportal.com/c/35207/f/653902/index.rss"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

This is bg.js

```
function fetch_feed(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 304) {
         console.log("Request successful");
          var data = xhr.responseText;
          callback(data);
        } else {
         console.log("Request not successful");
          callback(null);
        }
      }
    }
    // Note that any URL fetched here must be matched by a permission in
    // the manifest.json file!
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send();
}

function onMessage(request, sender, callback) {
         console.log("onmessage received with URL: " + request.url);
        if (request.action == 'fetch_feed') {
         fetch_feed(request.url, callback);
       }
}

console.log('listener installed');
// Wire up the listener.
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(onMessage);
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ziel"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally: popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        fetch_feed();
});

function fetch_feed() {
         console.log("starting");
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({'action' : 'fetch_feed', 'url' : 'http://www.heise.de/newsticker/heise-atom.xml'},
                function(response) {
                        console.log("Response successfully received: " + response);
                        display_stories(response);
                }
        );
}

function display_stories(xml) {
   $('#ziel').html("<h3>now displaying</h3>");
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with the `callback` parameter in the method `fetch_feed`. If I use `callback` inside `onMessage()` it's working fine, but in `fetch_feed` it never gets called. This is strange, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround (and simplification): I removed all the content from bg.js and moved the XMLHttpRequest to popup.js

So no more message passing ... which resolved my issue, but the problem is still kind of strange